# How to remove/disable pop out icons in document embedded in wordpress post with <iframe> from one drive

Tags: wordpress, embed, onedrive

```html
<iframe width="700" height="700" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" src="https://onedrive.live.com/embed?resid=2F7490B75A2F80E7%21997&amp;authkey=%21AJuSmNmWxMyfJCc&amp;em=2&amp;wdAllowInteractivity=False&amp;Item='Unsolved'!A5%3AL281&amp;wdInConfigurator=True"></iframe>
```

I want to embed one drive documents (Excel file) in my wordpress post. I have saved the document on one drive and copied the iframe code.

On the WordPress post I have added a custom HTML block and pasted the code inside the block. When document is displayed in the post then below the document display window three icons are appearing. Screen shot is attached herewith. Is it possible that we can remove these 3 icons or disable them.

[image: Screen shot of the icons to be removed]

Answer (score 0):

I'm having the same issue. You can't do that, instead export and save your excel worksheet or range of cells as (.html) and then put the src path of the html file in your html code and upload it on wordpress.